# tkinter after() problem, wont pass correct value to the label

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run the following Code, I get this:

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48BNm.png)

I want just the Bitcoin Value and also the current one, please help I am totally stuck.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time
time = 1000



def bitcoinTracker():  
    url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    price = soup.find('div', {'class':'priceValue___11gHJ'}).text
    return (price)


def collector():
    label = tk.Label(text="Bitcoin " + bitcoinTracker(), font="Arial 18")
    label.pack()
    root.after(time, collector)
root.after(time, collector)
root = tk.Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want just the Bitcoin Value"? Because that's exactly the output of your `bitcoinTracker` function

Comment: Please clarify more and give more information, also why did you import tkinter twice? Are you sure your code is working properly? Also no need to put parentheses when using return if it is only one item.

Comment: The screenshot of the Output shows my problem. I don't want a list, just a replacement. Regarding the cached value, I use the same code without tkinter and it works fine.

Comment: You should create the label once outside the function and then update its text inside the function.

Comment: @Philipp "Regarding the cached value, I use the same code without tkinter and it works fine" I just tested it without tkinter, and I get the same results as I do with tkinter. I think when you tested it before, you were "unlucky" and happened to witness the cache being updated.

Comment: @Philipp I just ran your code and it gives the same number over and over.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to that website in your browser and refresh the page, you'll see that the price doesn't update right away. It seems to show a cached value right away, then updates it with recent data a few seconds later. At the time of writing, I always see `$40,406.60` when initially viewing the page, then it updates after.

Without executing the Javascript that the page uses to fetch the updated info, you'll only see the old, cached data, until they update the cached data (it seems to happen every few minutes?).

You'd need to use a library like Selenium that is capable of executing Javascript. `requests` just gives you a single snapshot of the page at the time of fetching, and doesn't allow for anything else, like execution of Javascript to happen.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean replacing the following code

```
label = tk.Label(text="Bitcoin " + bitcoinTracker(), font="Arial 18")
```

with this?

```
label = tk.Label(bitcoinTracker(), font="Arial 18")
```

As for getting up to date values, there is an [API for coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/)
if that's okay for you.

Comment: You have to use a widget as the first argument to `Label`.